# want an alpine docker image with python-2.7.5

Tags: python-2.7, docker, alpine-linux

I want a custom alpine docker image with minimal size and then have python 2.7.5 on top of it, but when i go to install python using apk add python it install the latest python2.7 version(python 2.7.14). Is it possible to define a custom python build to be installed on the alpine docker?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is a reason they don't support 2.7.5 but if you really need it, you could copy a Dockerfile from one of the [official 2.7 repos](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/8717dc2523c8093990cb958bb8c47ade6f851c05/2.7/alpine3.4/Dockerfile) and change the version from 2.7.14 to 2.7.5 (and whatever other changes suit your needs) and see if it builds ok.